# Extending a type to allow additional fields

Tags: typescript

I have a generic method designed to create nodes for a database, and I want this method to allow both known fields from a type and any additional fields.

Here's the method in question:

```
create<A extends string, P extends Partial<Record<keyof T['fields'], any>>>(
    alias: A,
    node: T,
    parameters: P,
): this {
    const properties = Object.entries(parameters)
        .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: "${value}"`)
        .join(', ');

    this.query.push(`CREATE (${alias}:${node.label} {${properties}})`);
    return this;
}
```

When I use this method:

```
const query = this.cypherBuilder
  .create('m', Author, {
    name,
    image,
    description,
    lifeYears,
    didntExisit: 22,  // This field isn't part of Author's fields.
  })
  .return('m')
  .build();
```

TypeScript didn't complains about the didntExisit field, which isn't part of Author's fields.

Comment: If you don't want broader types to be permitted, why `P extends ...`?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when we paste it into our own IDEs, without unrelated issues like undefined types or values.  Right now I just see [a bunch of errors](https://tsplay.dev/NVl2vW) which I'd have to work on fixing to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to use a mapped type to restrict the keys of the parameters object based on the type's known fields. Here's how you can achieve this:

```
type RestrictedParameters<T> = Partial<{ [K in keyof T['fields']]: any }>;

class CypherBuilder<T> {
    // ... other methods ...

    create<A extends string>(
        alias: A,
        node: T,
        parameters: RestrictedParameters<T>,
    ): this {
        const properties = Object.entries(parameters)
            .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: "${value}"`)
            .join(', ');

        this.query.push(`CREATE (${alias}:${node.label} {${properties}})`);
        return this;
    }
}
```